# Converting my single page site to html5

Tags: php, html, xhtml

At the moment I have a single page site (html/php) I created for someone about 2 years ago.  I'm about to add an admin panel and plan on starting with html5 for it.  I'm curious what I will need to do to my single page besides switching the `<!doctype>` to just `html`.

Here's a bit of my single page `index.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="descriptions" content="meta desc">
    <meta name="keywords" content="meta, keywords">

    <!--imports the main css file-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

I know first I'll change my doctype to `<!doctype html>` but don't I also have to remove extra properties of my `link` and `script` tags? Namely the `type` property?

Currently this is a simple 1 page site, so I thought it would be a great place to start.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be it. Do that and then put the URL in http://validator.w3.org/ to see what html 5 errors you have.

Also since it will not be XML I think you'll want to remove the forward slashes from the end of the meta and link tags. See Useless Code's comment below regarding the type attributes.

The validator will tell you each problem until your html 5 is valid.

Comment: You should remove the `type` attribute from the `<script>` tags, it is not needed, all browsers default to JS. I'm not as sure about CSS, but if you have a `<link>` whose `rel` attribute is set to `stylesheet`, it should also default to CSS.

Comment: Did not know that. I have updated my answer and I'm going to go remove type attributes from my site's script tags now.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML 5 code would look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="meta desc">
    <meta name="keywords" content="meta, keywords">

    <title>Title</title>

    <!--imports the main css file-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen">
    <script src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Some explanations:

- xmlns is no longer needed. Elements in HTML5 don't need to be explicitly delcared.
- I'd go with charset meta before title. Otherwise, IE users might be left in the open in front of an XSS attack. (https://code.google.com/p/doctype-mirror/wiki/ArticleUtf7)
- on the second meta, the name attribute should be description, not descriptions.
- there's no need for forward in html (at the end of meta, links). those were mandatory in xhtml.
- when referencing link and scripts, you can choose not to mention the type attribute. It is considered redundant as the defaults will kick in (for link you would probably use css, and for script js)

If you want to find out more about HTML 5 - here are some good places to start (stuff that you can read and enjoy while at it, compared to the actual standard):

- http://diveintohtml5.info/  - free e-book by Mark Pilgrim

Comment: Excellent ebook recommendation.  Thanks for your helpful explanation!